# Visual Studio Team Services shows Error TF30040 on "get latest Version"

Tags: migration, azure-devops, opshub

We did a migration (with OpsHub) from TFS to Visual Studio Team Services.

Now we get an Error TF30040 "The database is not correctly configured. Contact you Team Foundation Server administrator.". This seems to occur when there is a conflicting change.

Steps to reproduce:

- On machine 1, checkout and change a file
- On machine 2, checkout and change the same file
- On machine 2, check in the change
- On machine 1, do a get latest by right clicking on the project or solution (while the file is still checked out)

On TFS this used to get the latest versions of the files that not have been checked out. But checked out files would remain checked out. What are we doing wrong? This was not a problem in TFS, so I guess VSTS should also allow this. Or is this a setting?

We are not using the GIT version control, but the "Team Foundation Version Control"

I can do a workaround by hitting "check in" on the conflicting files. VS will show the "resolve conflict" window. I choose for "keep local" and that it will work as expected, but that is not how it's supposed to work in my opinion.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like something went horribly wrong with the migration. These operations are supposed to just work. I'd consider submitting a support call with Microsoft and/or OpsHub to have this diagnosed. I'd expect it will be hard to  diagnose this one yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue <s>should be fixed now. Please try it again.</s> is still live and Microsoft investigates. Issue Details: [TF30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2429485)

> Posted by Wil [MSFT] on 3/3/2016 at 12:54 PM
>
> Thank you for letting us know. We deployed a fix just recently to fix
>   this issue. Please let us know if it is still occurring. Thank you
>   again for bringing this to our attention.

And for the get latest feature, it will get the latest version for a checked out file and prompt resolve conflict dialog if needed when the file version on server is newer than local.

For example, in the steps you provided, assume the file version is C1 on the begin.

On Step 1, the file version on server and machine1 is still C1 after you made a change without check in. If you get the latest on this step, the file will not be downloaded.

On Step 3, the file version on server has been updated to C2 as you check in the change from machine2. But the file version on machine1 is still C1.

Now on Step 4, the file with C2 version will be downloaded when you get latest from server since C2 on server is new than C1 on machine.

Refer to this article for more information: [How “Get Latest Version” Really Works in TFS Source Control?](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/srlteam/2009/04/13/how-get-latest-version-really-works-in-tfs-source-control/)